# How to combine 'blocktanslate' with 'humanize' tag in templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, localization

`blocktranslate` allows me to display a localized plural, whereas `humanize` allows me to display a grouped-by-hundred number.

Each of them works when used independently but I'd like to have both in the same time.

I've tried:

(`words_number` is the integer sent by the view)

```
{% load humanize %}
{% blocktranslate count counter=words_number %}
1 word
{% plural %}
{{ counter|intcomma }} words
{% endblocktranslate %}
```

But it displays: `words` (empty space where the number should be)

**EDIT: Before a solution will be found, I'm using Javascript to group by hundred:**

```
{% blocktranslate count counter=words_number %}
1 word
{% plural %}
<span id="counter">{{ counter }}</span> words
{% endblocktranslate %}

<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    let counter = document.getElementById('counter');   
    let counter_loc = parseInt(counter.innerHTML).toLocaleString();
    counter.innerHTML = counter_loc;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant translation?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... For the moment there's no other localization than English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the documentation for the [`blocktranslate` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktranslate-template-tag) to use filters or expressions on variables you need to **bind** them to some local variable using `with`, so you can do something like follows:

```
{% load humanize %}
{% blocktranslate with count_humanized=words_number|intcomma count counter=words_number %}
1 word
{% plural %}
{{ count_humanized }} words
{% endblocktranslate %}
```